# App does not open when using "my apps" bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook-canvas

I habe a problem with a facebook app that is currently under development (`http://apps.facebook.com/199067363458724`, points to `http://localhost:3000`)): I can visit the app url without problems, but when I click on the "quick access app bar", my app can't be loaded (see screenshot).

I tried some debugging, but I can't find a reason for this behaviour. After the click facebook tries to access `https://apps.facebook.com/ajax/canvas.php?__a=1&fb_app_name=199067363458724&uri=%2F199067363458724%2F%3Ffb_source%3Dcanvas_bkmk_top%26count%3D0&__user=XXXXXXXX` with an Ajax request , but a "302 Not found" is returned. When I open `https://apps.facebook.com/199067363458724/?fb_source=canvas_bkmk_top&count=0` manually, all is working fine.

Any ideas?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I think instead of `http://localhost:3000` you should have an IP

Comment: It's just a test app, I have another app running with a real domain - and this one has the same problem. So it's not because of localhost...

Comment: Have you enabled authenticated referrals?

Comment: I don't think so. I haven't heard of it before :), and in the app settings "Enhanced Auth Dialog" is deactivated...

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I found the solution for the problem: Set a namespace for the app! (http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8718106/set-human-app-name-for-facebook-app)

Then you can use http://apps.facebook.com/appid and http://apps.facebook.com/namespace , and all links go the namespace URL.